# conditional target in Snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

I have 3 files:

```
output/file_2.txt
output/file_4.txt
output/file_6.txt
```

Each one of these files have sample names inside, for example `output/file2.txt` looks like this, other files follow same logic:

```
sample1
sample2
sample3
```

Now I have a function that reads through all the files and stores in a list the sample names:

```
def extract_ind():
    l = []
    for n in [2,4,6]:
            with open(f'output/file_{n}.txt') as f:
                l.extend([line.strip() for line in f])
    return l
```

Then I have the default rule that collects everything and the rule that extracts samples and creates new files with sample names :

```
rule all:
    input: 
        expand('output/file_{n}_{sample}.vcf.gz',n=[2,4,6],sample=extract_ind())

rule extract_samples:
    input:
        vcf = 'muscle/file_{n}.vcf.gz'
    output:
        vcf_dir = 'output/file_{n}_{sample}.vcf.gz'
    shell:
        'bcftools query -l {input.vcf} | xargs -I {{}} bcftools view -O z -s {{}} -o {output.vcf_dir} {input}'
```

The way this is designed currently, rule `all` will use `itertools product` to generate all combinations of sample names and files:
For example `file_2.txt` will have results like this:

```
output/file_2_sample1.vcf.gz
output/file_2_sample2.vcf.gz
output/file_2_sample3.vcf.gz
output/file_2_sample4.vcf.gz -----> ops, don't want that `sample4` is coming from `file_4`
```

In order to overcome this issue I naively created an input function, but I guess this is not the way to go since input functions are used for inputs and not target outputs right ?

```
def use_ind(wildcards):
    l = []
    if wildcards.n == 2:
        with open(f'output/file_2.txt') as f:
                l.extend([line.strip() for line in f])
                return l
        
    elif wildcards.n == 4:
        with open(f'output/file_4.txt') as f:
                l.extend([line.strip() for line in f])
                return l
    elif wildcards.n == 6:
        with open(f'output/file_6.txt') as f:
                l.extend([line.strip() for line in f])
                return l
```

I ultimately would like to create some logic to have something like this as result:

```
output/file_2_sample1.vcf.gz
output/file_2_sample2.vcf.gz
output/file_2_sample3.vcf.gz
output/file_4_sample4.vcf.gz
output/file_4_sample6.vcf.gz
etc....
```

That is every file should only contain samples that are pertinent to the file itself. Hope to be clear, if not let me know and I will try to formulate better the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the following, I will assume your `output/file_{n}.txt` are inputs, otherwise you will need to utilize checkpoints for the rule that creates them.

Don't be overwhelmed with rules and expands.  At the end, `rule all`'s input is a list of files you want.  You can make that list with any valid python.  Let's say you don't know the values for `n` ahead of time, but you have a directory of files that have samples in them.

```
def use_ind(n):
    return [line.strip() for line in open(f'output/file_{n}.txt')]

n_values = glob_wildcards('output/file_{n}.txt').n

target_files = [f'output/file_{n}_{sample}.vcf.gz'
                for n in n_values
                for sample in use_ind(n)]

rule all:
    input: target_files
```

You should also try to have the outputs of different rules go into different directories so wildcard matching is more likely to work how you expect.