# Snakemake, producing list of files that are created within the pipeline

Tags: snakemake

This is my first snakemake workflow, so it might be that I'm overcomplicating things.

My workflow takes as input the 'database query' for downloading some files, which is specified in my 'config.yaml'. **It means that I do not know the names of the files that will be downloaded before running the pipeline.**

```
# configfile: "config.yaml"
# DATABASE = config["database"]    
# database: '("Apis"[Organism] OR Apis[All Fields]) AND (latest[filter] AND "representative genome"[filter] AND all[filter] NOT anomalous[filter])'

DATABASE = '("Apis"[Organism] OR Apis[All Fields]) AND (latest[filter] AND "representative genome"[filter] AND all[filter] NOT anomalous[filter])'
```

What I want to do is to:

1. Create a genome list: call a database with my query and extract the links to the files (`create_genome_list`). (Here, I use [entrez](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/entrez-direct))
2. Next, I want to download the files using the collected links (`download_genome`)
3. Files are zipped, so I want to unzip them (`unzip_genome`)
4. Finally, I would like to create a list of all downloaded and unzipped files... and here I struggle. (`make_summary_table`)

I can run my snakemake on steps 1-3 when I call one of the expected output files with the following:

- `snakemake -p database/GCA_000184785.2_Aflo_1.1_genomic/GCA_000184785.2_Aflo_1.1_genomic.fna  --use-conda`
- It gives me links to all expected files (5) in folder `/temp`,
- and 1 downloaded and unzipped file: `/database/GCA_000184785.2_Aflo_1.1_genomic/GCA_000184785.2_Aflo_1.1_genomic.fna`

My snakemake for steps 1-3 looks like this:

```
rule create_genome_list:
output: touch("temp/{genome}")

conda:  "entrez_env.yaml"
message: "Creating the genomes list..."

shell:
    r"""
    esearch -db assembly -query '{DATABASE}' \
    | esummary \
    | xtract -pattern DocumentSummary -element FtpPath_GenBank \
    | while read -r line ; 
    do
        fname=$(echo $line | grep -o 'GCA_.*' | sed 's/$/_genomic.fna.gz/');
        wildcard=$(echo $fname | sed -e 's!.fna.gz!!');

        echo "$line/$fname" > temp/$wildcard;
        #echo $wildcard >> list_of_genomes.txt

    done
   
    """   


rule download_genome:
    output: touch("database/{genome}/{genome}.fna.gz")

    input:  "temp/{genome}"

    shell:
       r"""
       GENOME_LINK=$(cat {input})
       GENOME="${{GENOME_LINK##*/}}"
       wget -P ./database/{wildcards.genome}/ $GENOME_LINK 
       """


rule unzip_genome:
   output: touch("database/{genome}/{genome}.fna")

   input:  "database/{genome}/{genome}.fna.gz"

   shell: "gunzip {input}"
```

My problem starts when I want to create the final rule, which will wrap up the results of my pipeline. In my real pipeline, I do some additional analyses with downloaded genomes, and at the end, I want to join all partial results obtained per single genome into one table. Here I post a toy example, which I believe reflects my problem the best.

I guess there is some way to extract the genomes' names so I could call them in the final summarising rule's input.

**I approached it in an ugly way** by listing files in `temp/` and using them in `expand()` like follow:

```
GENOMES = os.listdir("temp/")

rule make_summary_table:
    output: "summary_table.txt"

    input:  expand("database/{genome}/{genome}.fna", genome = GENOMES)

    shell:
        """
        echo {input} >> {output}
        echo " " >> {output}
        """
```

But it works only when `/temp` exists before running the pipeline. And it produces the `summary_table.txt` with 5 positions only when I run steps 1-3 before (otherwise, it produces an empty file).

I am also afraid that in my real pipeline, it might happen that not all genomes will produce partial results on time the last summarising rule will be called. But maybe Snakemake handles it somehow (by waiting?) once all the inputs are specified.

**-----------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------**

I have tried to implement `checkpoint` as a possible solution as follow:

```
DATABASE = '("Apis"[Organism] OR Apis[All Fields]) AND (latest[filter] AND "representative genome"[filter] AND all[filter] NOT anomalous[filter])'

rule all:
    input:    "summary_table.txt"
    
checkpoint create_genome_list:
    output: directory("temp/")

    conda:  "entrez_env.yaml"
    
    shell:
        r"""
        esearch -db assembly -query '{DATABASE}' \
        | esummary \
        | xtract -pattern DocumentSummary -element FtpPath_GenBank \
        | while read -r line ; 
        do
            fname=$(echo $line | grep -o 'GCA_.*' | sed 's/$/_genomic.fna.gz/');
            wildcard=$(echo $fname | sed -e 's!.fna.gz!!');

            echo "$line/$fname" > temp/$wildcard;
            #echo $wildcard >> list_of_genomes.txt

        done
       
        """   
   
rule download_genome:
    output: touch("database/{genome}/{genome}.fna.gz")
    
    input:  "temp/{genome}"

    
    shell:
        r"""
        GENOME_LINK=$(cat {input})
        GENOME="${{GENOME_LINK##*/}}"
        wget -P ./database/{wildcards.genome}/ $GENOME_LINK 
        """

rule unzip_genome:
    output: "database/{genome}/{genome}.fna"

    input:  "database/{genome}/{genome}.fna.gz"
    
    shell:
        r"""
        gunzip {input}
        """        

def aggregate_input(wildcards):
      checkpoint_output = checkpoints.create_genome_list.get(**wildcards).output[0]
      return expand("database/{genome}/{genome}.fna",
                  i=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output, "{genome}.fna")).genome)

rule make_summary_table:
    output: "summary_table.txt"

    input:  aggregate_input

    shell:
        """
        echo {input} >> {output}
        echo " " >> {output}
        """
```

But cannot overcome the error: `InputFunctionException in line 73 (rule make_summary_table) of ~/snakemake_test/Snakefile: WildcardError: No values given for wildcard 'genome'. Wildcards:`

Comment: You could try using checkpoints to reevaluate the list of input files before snakemake executes the last step, see here for details: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution

Comment: For an example on how to apply `checkpoints` for such a case, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74769498/snakemake-wildcards-using-wildcarded-files-from-directory-output

Comment: Also, a snakefiles is a superset of Python and so you can execute arbitrary python at the outset. If there is a way to make the list in Python you can then use that if you know Python, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73169073/8508004). That may be a way to replace your ' ugly way'?

Comment: Thank you for your comments @euronion and @Wayne! I've tried to implement `checkpoints` solution but cannot overcome an error. Please, if you have some tips check out my update

Answer (score 0):

For your updated code to work you need to apply atleast the following two fixes:

1. <s>Redefine the `rule` as `checkpoint`</s> (not necessary, see edit note below)
2. Expand all wildcards in the `checkpoint`-related function (your expand leaves `{genome}` un-expanded as it expands `i` which is not defined as a wildcard and thus does nothing.

The relevant code lines:

```py
def aggregate_input(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.create_genome_list.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    return expand(
        "database/{genome}/{genome}.fna",
        genome=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output, "{genome}.fna")).genome,
    )


rule make_summary_table:
    output:
        "summary_table.txt",
    input:
        aggregate_input,
    shell:
        """
        echo {input} >> {output}
        echo " " >> {output}
        """
```

Give it a try and let us know if it works!

edit: Sorry, I realised that the correct rule was already converted to a `checkpoint` and my 1. point is invalid. I've updated the answer above.

Comment: Thank you for your encouraging answer! I've applied your suggestions, and now the code is error-free... but. It seems that rules `download_genomes` and `unzip_genome` are skipped. After calling for "summary_table.txt" the folder `temp/` is created and it contains all 5 links as desired. The "summary_table.txt" is also created but empty... Must admit, that I was assuming placing wildcard `{genome}.fna` (output of `rule unzip_genome`) in `aggregate_input` will solve this issue...

Comment: What is the reason the rules are skipped? Does snakemake not consider them or are they skipped because maybe the files already exist? Use the flag `-Fn` to force dry-run of your whole snakemake workflow.

Comment: It's rather they are not called at all... Look, after hitting: `snakemake -Fn "summary_table.txt"  --use-conda`, I've received: "Building DAG of jobs...
Job counts:
 count jobs
 1 create_genome_list
 1 make_summary_table
 2
checkpoint create_genome_list:
    output: temp/
    jobid: 1
Downstream jobs will be updated after completion.

checkpoint make_summary_table:
    input: <TBD>
    output: summary_table.txt
    jobid: 0
Downstream jobs will be updated after completion.

Job counts:
 count jobs
 1 create_genome_list
 1 make_summary_table
 2
This was a dry-run..."

Comment: For each genome, `checkpoint create_genome_list` creates a file in `temp/`, right? How are those files called? It could be that the `glob_wildcards(...)` does not contain the correct filename format

Comment: You are right! The wildcards didn't match - I replaced `{genome}.fna` with `{genome}` in `glob_wildcards(...)`, and it started to run also earlier skipped rules!

Comment: I'm not sure if it deserves a separate question, but is there a way to avoid passing .snakemake.timestamp in inputs? It falls into my wildcards in all rules and messes up the whole pipeline. Due to `touch()` in rule `download_genome`, the `.snakemake.timestamp.fna.gz` is created... Is it another way to overcome it without modifying the wildcard in this rule?

Comment: Yes, that would be a seperate question. You can always restrict which type of filenames / filename parts the wildcards should match (wildcard_constraints). Look it up in the snakemake docs ;-)

Comment: I've just tried  with global `wildcard_constraints: genome = 'GCA.+'`, but then it seems that `timestamp` is taken as a wildcard in `aggregate_input`, so then the following `expand("database/{genome}/{genome}.fna"` cannot be found... The exact error is "Missing input files for rule make_summary_table:
database/.snakemake_timestamp/.snakemake_timestamp.fna"